# Непонятное поведение терминала Ubuntu

Tags: linux, vps, terminal

На vps сервере при некоторых операциях (apt-get install /remove) в терминал начинает бесконечно выводиться буква у таким образом:

у

у

у

у

Comment: это проделки утилиты [yes](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yes_(Unix))

Comment: хм. А что её может запускать?

Comment: Обычно она запускается в pipe к stdin другой команды, и её вывод не попадает в stdout терминала. Вероятно, либо вы запускаете какие-то некорректные скрипты, либо ставите пакеты, в которых оно некорректно запускается.

Comment: Вы можете посмотреть дерево процессов на сервере в другой сессии.

Comment: спасибо за разъяснение. У меня проблемы с apache tomcat. Не могу его теперь ни переустановить, ни удалить

Comment: @alex банально, но вы пробовали сервак перезагружать? у apt должен схоронятся лога, посмотрите что там.

Comment: конечно перезагружал. В итоге плюнул и переустановил ос. Теперь всё работает )